# Load iFrame in Bootstrap accordion only when opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have the iframes inside the bootstrap 3 accordion to load only when the item is opened. Right now all iframes load at the same time when page loads and it causes the page to load for a long time. How to stop the iframes loading until the accordion item is opened?

Here is my collapse code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
                Title 1 goes here
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"> <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                Title 2 goes here
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"> <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the SRC attribute blank and then hook into/setup your own event listener for when an accordion item is opened to set the SRC attribute of the iframe then